# Submit comments from my website to the users facebook wall

Tags: facebook

Currently on my website - I have a form which users use to post comments on the website. I want to add an extra check box - that says "Post to my facebook" wall.
So if they check that - the comment they post on my website - should also be posted on their website. They should not have to type the comment again.

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook Connect, which is largely a javascript-enabled connection between your site and Facebook, is the answer.

http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php

Not terribly difficult to implement, but you need to be savvy with Javascript. And if you've got your own user membership db (as you likely do), you'll need to wire up the links between your users and facebook id's.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction steve - will take a look at that link

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use connect as steve mentioned, specifically the [FB.Connect.streamPublish](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/?u=facebook.jslib.FB.Connect.streamPublish) method. I think what you really want to do post *your* link as a shared stream item, and use the user's comment as the `user_message` field. The attachment's description would probably be something like "I commented on this article".

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the [comments box](http://developers.facebook.com/tools.php?connect_wizard&wizard=comments), coupled with Facebook Connect it should accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thanks Soufiane - the user is not posting a comment. The app is similar to twitter where the user is writing something about himself - so whatever he is posting on my website - I want that to be posted on his facebook profile as well if he chooses to.